# How to Refresh Spring Boot Configuration Info with Using Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I would like to ask how to refresh spring boot configuration info with using spring cloud config. Would you please give me some advice? Many thanks.

Comment: do you want to use refreshed configuration in spring boot application?

Answer (score 1):

If your spring boot application is a client of Spring Cloud Configuration Server and use itself as single point of truth in the application configuration let's say retrieve application.properties/yml from the config server, you can benefit of @RefreshScope. in this case if you do a post to the /refresh if you use spring boot 1.x or /actuator/refresh if you use spring boot 2.x  all the bean that are have are annotated as @RefreshScope will be refreshed.